# Can Terraform mask variables in the console output?

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

I wanted to post this as a feature request but I wanted to see if anyone else has found some clever way of doing this before I post. Or maybe someone from Hashicorp can tell me this will be a feature in the coming

I have looked high and low for some way to mask variables from the console when running `terraform apply/show`. Preferably trying to mask variables using a *local-exec* provisioner when passing variables to a script.

A tool called *[Terrahelp](https://github.com/opencredo/terrahelp)* is the only thing I can find that will do this but it will only apply to variables in a `tfvars` file which doesn't allow interpolations. This doesn't help since we are trying to use Vault to keep secrets out of the terraform files.

```
Current Versions
Terraform v0.11.7
provider.null v1.0.0
provider.template v1.0.0
provider.vault v1.3.1
provider.vsphere v1.8.1
```

**Use Case**

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "&'${path.module}\\scripts\\script.ps1' -name ${var.node_name} -pass '${var.pass}' -user ${var.user} -server ${var.server}"
    interpreter = ["Powershell", "-Command"]
  }
```

**Attempted Solutions**
I'm using Vault to keep secrets out of the Terraform files, so I am using the vault provider and calling data from it. I have tried to create a module and output the secrets with the `sensitive = true` value and then calling that module to use the secrets however that still shows in the console.

**Proposal**

Allow some kind of sensitive value much like output to variables within Terraform. So if scripts like the above are called in the console they won't show sensitive variable information.

References
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16114
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16643

Comment: did you try resource `aws_ssm_parameter` and its output, it is marked already ( `value:  <sensitive>`), maybe you can get some hints from it.

Comment: If you're using Vault, you could possibly configure one-time passwords. Then it doesn't matter if they are in the logs or not as they aren't valid passwords once they have been used (or expired).

Answer (score 3):

Terraform 13 was released since this question was asked, and allows variables to be marked as `sensitive` and not shown in the console.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html#sensitive-suppressing-values-in-cli-output

Comment: Can we mark this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback, the passwords cannot be set for a one time use as some of these are service accounts in AD that do other things which those applications cannot handle constant password changes.

We did find a solution through another product which is Azure/Azure DevOps. We are storing credentials in key vaults in Azure which Azure DevOps has access to and using Azure DevOps pipelines to send terraform code to our Build Server. Azure DevOps seems to act as a shell which hides any secrets from the console and it works pretty well. I would recommend it to anyone who is also looking to hide secrets from terraform files/command line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it for a few on-premise services:

1 - `var.password` doesn't actually stores a password. Rather, it stores the name of an environment variable.

2 - My scripts get passwords from those environment variables.

3 - I have a small program that loads secrets to environment and clears them for `terraform apply`.

So in the end I just bypass Terraform for secrets used by scripts. Not ideal, but I also couldn't find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think https://github.com/cloudposse/tfmask might be what you're looking for:

> Command line utility to mask sensitive output from a transform plan or terraform apply.

You first set an environment variable to filter the masked keys (admittedly there's some manual work involved here):

```sh
export TFMASK_VALUES_REGEX="(?i)^.*(secret|password|oauth|token|key).*$"
```

And then pipe terraform commands through `tfmask`, resulting in masked output:

```sh
terraform plan | tfmask
```

Answer (score 0):

This is self-advertising, but I create a tool called [terramask](https://github.com/farzadmf/terramask) that works with Terraform 0.12.

[Issues](https://github.com/farzadmf/terramask/issues) are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell if this is your use case or not, but one strategy that we've used with sensitive variables is to make use of the default Terraform behavior to use [environment variables to set TF variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html#tf_var_name), e.g.,

```
variable "sensitive_variable" {
  type = "string"
}
```

```sh
sensitive_var=$(curl url/with/remote/value)
export TF_VAR_sensitive_variable=$sensitive_var
terraform apply
```